# Reflecting shader uniform names in Metal

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, shader, metal

Suppose I have the following uniform buffer in my shader:

```
typedef struct
{
    matrix_float4x4 modelview_projection_matrix;
    float someValue;
} uniforms_t;
```

How do I get someValue's location in C++ or Objective-C? I want to do something like this:

```
void Shader::SetFloat( const char* name, float value )
```

where name would be 'someValue'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with a solution by examining [BGFX](https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx/blob/master/src/renderer_mtl.mm)'s source code:

```
    NSError* error = NULL;
    MTLRenderPipelineReflection* reflectionObj;
    MTLPipelineOption option = MTLPipelineOptionBufferTypeInfo | MTLPipelineOptionArgumentInfo;
    id <MTLRenderPipelineState> pso = [device newRenderPipelineStateWithDescriptor:pipelineStateDescriptor options:option reflection:&reflectionObj error:&error];

    for (MTLArgument *arg in reflectionObj.vertexArguments)
    {
        NSLog(@"Found arg: %@\n", arg.name);

        if (arg.bufferDataType == MTLDataTypeStruct)
        {
            for( MTLStructMember* uniform in arg.bufferStructType.members )
            {
                NSLog(@"uniform: %@ type:%lu, location: %lu", uniform.name, (unsigned long)uniform.dataType, (unsigned long)uniform.offset);         
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how to I get binding points/indexs for properties of struct? Like say I have texture/buffer defined in struct with [texture[n]], how to I get that 'n'?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [*Specifying Resources for a Render Command Encoder*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Render-Ctx/Render-Ctx.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH7-SW10) section of Apple's [*Metal Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

As a very basic explanation...

1. Declare your `uniforms_t` structure (which will typically be a single structure containing all the uniforms for a particular shader function) as an argument of a *Metal* shader function, and associate it with a specific buffer index (eg. `[[ buffer(0) ]]`) as part of your shader function declaration.
2. From your app code, copy the contents of your `uniforms_t` structure into a `MTLBuffer`, at some offset.
3. From your app code, invoke the `MTLRenderCommandEncoder` `setVertexBuffer:offset:atIndex:` or `setFragmentBuffer:offset:atIndex:` methods to associate the contents of the `MTLBuffer` (at the offset where you copied your `uniforms_t` structure) with the buffer index you declared in your shader function. This basically tells the shader function which `MTLBuffer` to look in (and where in that buffer) for the value of that function argument.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question because my renderer can't know beforehand the buffer layout. I'm writing a game engine and can't hardcode buffers into the engine because every application can use different kinds of buffers. That's why I must reflect the buffers from shader code and just found MTLRenderPipelineReflection, MTLArgument and friends. I may be able to solve this myself soon and will post an answer if so.